# Word - Fieldfunctions are not executed automatically

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I experimented with the `CTRL + F9` feature in word where you can call some methods, e.g. a method which gets the current page number.

However, now the method strings are not executed anymore and I always have to right click them and press "Fieldfunctions on/off" everytime.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Most fields will not update automatically. If you want them to update then you click them and press F9, otherwise you can also go to the print preview and it should update the entire document.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to update fields manually; there is no way for them get auto-updated while you are working on your document. The fastest way to update fields is to go the print preview `CTRL` + `P` and back from it `Esc`.